# @user_script:1: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: java, redis, lua

Following is my lua script

```
if redis.call('sismember',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])==1
then redis.call('srem',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])
else return 0
end
store = tonumber(redis.call('hget',KEYS[2],'capacity'))
store = store + 1
redis.call('hset',KEYS[2],'capacity',store)
return 1
```

when I run this srcipt in Java, An exception like

```
@user_script:1: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

throws, the Java code is like

```
Object ojb = jedis.evalsha(sha,2,userName.getBytes(),
                id.getBytes(),id.getBytes()) ;
```

where userName is "tau" and id is "002" in my code,
and I test the type of "tau" and "002" as follows,

```
127.0.0.1:6379> type tau
set
127.0.0.1:6379> type 002
hash
```

and exactly, the content of them are :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall 002
name
"鏁版嵁搴撲粠鍒犲簱鍒拌窇璺?
teacher
"taochq"
capacity
54
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers tau
002
004
001
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Now I'm so confused and don't know what's wrong, any help will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite verbose - you're trying to perform an operation on key of the wrong type.

Run [`MONITOR`](https://redis.io/commands/monitor) alongside and then your script - then you'll be able to spot the error easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try your script as:

```
EVAL "if redis.call('sismember',KEYS[1],ARGV[1])==1 \n then redis.call('srem',KEYS[1],ARGV[1]) \n else return 0 \n end \n local store = tonumber(redis.call('hget',KEYS[2],'capacity')) \n store = store + 1 \n redis.call('hset',KEYS[2],'capacity',store) \n return 1" 2 tau 002 002
```

You'll see if it works. Most likely, `userName.getBytes()` and `id.getBytes()` are not returning what you expect. Use `MONITOR` as Itamar suggests to see what's actually reaching the server.

You'll get a separate a different issue: `Script attempted to create global variable 'store'`. Add `local` to the 5th line:

```
local store = tonumber(redis.call('hget',KEYS[2],'capacity'))
```